# Changing the xml tags in rss feed in magento

Tags: xml, magento, rss

I have enabled Rss feeds in magento. The xml output it is generating has information wrapped in title, link and description tags wrapped within item tag.

But I want to output xml feed with tags product, part number,name, url, description wrapped within products tag.

How do I do this in magento? Changing the labels in app/core/Mage/Rss/Catalog isn't helping?

Comment: Okay I figured out that the RSS has a specified set of tags to be used as part of the specification so hence trying to change that was breaking it entirely. I instead need to use a custom xml feed generator and not RSS